# Table '' could not be loaded

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I was hoping someone out there may have experienced this before.

I have a database that (as far as I'm aware) is in perfect working order. I have no problems with it whatsoever. I'm trying to add a column to some of the tables but when I save the changes I get the following message

[image]

This error message is then stuck in a loop and the only thing I can do is kill the SQL Management Studio process.

The database exists, the table exists, I can run any query I want against it, I just can't make any changes to it.

The steps I'm taking are:

1. Right click table
2. Select "design"
3. Right click "add new column" in designer
4. Fill in the details as normal
5. Click Save

Anyone know how I can resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you're trying to execute.  Trust me: Nobody cares about the details of your schema.

Comment: There is no code. My steps are outlined above.

Comment: Actually, you are running SQL code.  SSMS just generates it automatically and hides it from you.  To see it, when you would save, instead go Table Designer > Generate Change Script.

Comment: Same error on generating code.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you haven't specified the name of the table.  The name of the table should be between the two single quotes.

Without knowing how you're doing this it's hard to tell more, but the first two possibilities off the top of my head are:

- If you're looping through tables in code to do something, you may be hitting a record with no table name.
- If it's pure SQL, perhaps an error in your syntax

Comment: But where do I do that? I don't normally. Right click table -> design -> add new column -> Save

Comment: Well that's helpful.  At least now we know that you're not doing this in code. Perhaps you should list the steps you take to get this error.  But that said, if you're using SQL Server Management Studio then this isn's a coding error, and this is the wrong web site to ask this one.  Perhaps [DBA.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Good luck.  I'm keeping this answer out there only so that others don't try to answer.  Maybe a mod could delete this question?